# RavenDB Patch API: Set based operations using ScriptedPatchRequest: ExceptionHandling

Tags: ravendb

Thanks to the excellent documentation at http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/set-based-operations I was able to execute a skript on my RavenDB.

I'm now wondering what happens if the skript contains invalid data, such as unknown Properties, DivideByZero exception, etc.

Is there any Exception handling? How can I figure out which entities couldn't be updated?

Thanks in advance,

Best

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an error, and the process will stop part way through.
You'll get the error through the response. Along with the entity that caused it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried the following script:

    this.Quanitity = 1 / 0

But the API returned the following value:

    {  
      "Document": "mydocuments/1",
      "Result": 
      {
        "PatchResult": "Patched",
        "Document": null
      },
      "Debug": []
    }

Why is the API telling me that the document was patched correctly even though there should be a DivideByZero exception thrown.